# branch out of range compile error

Tags: iphone, compiler-errors

I get the following compile errors when compiling to the device. (When compiling to simulator everything is OK)

> /var/folders/3B/3BAjD+ANHHmfh-eIWrtXDU+++TI/-Tmp-/cc-hojnUD.s:1784380:branch
>   out of range
>   /var/folders/3B/3BAjD+ANHHmfh-eIWrtXDU+++TI/-Tmp-/cc-hojnUD.s:1784372:branch
>   out of range
>   /var/folders/3B/3BAjD+ANHHmfh-eIWrtXDU+++TI/-Tmp-/cc-hojnUD.s:1784364:branch
>   out of range
>   /var/folders/3B/3BAjD+ANHHmfh-eIWrtXDU+++TI/-Tmp-/cc-hojnUD.s:1784356:branch
>   out of range

In various places I read something about turning off "Thumb". I don't really know if this would resolve the issue since I can't find this compile option anywhere.

I have some pretty large init files (with more than 50k lines) doing nothing else but defining NSMutuable array and stuf like that.

I can't get my app to compile for the iPhone anymore because of this error.

Do you have any idea what I can do about this?

ps. I use Xcode 4.2 with Apple LLVM 3.0 (using ARM, so I can't change the compiler)

Many thanks!

Comment: Is your init file one huge function? If so, it may help to break the function into smaller pieces and have a master function call the pieces in order.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely helped. Now I can compile to iPhone. However, running Instruments with Build for Profile still hangs - I filed a bug report with Apple for this. If you could put your comment as an anwswer I will be glad to mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Moved from comment).* Is your init file one huge function? If so, it may help to break the function into smaller pieces and have a master function call the pieces in order.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known linker bug (rdar://16186742). The problem is with the armv7 compiler, when it needs to synthesize branch islands to jump further than 16 MB, and the jump happens to be *exactly* 16 MB. The work around is to rearrange the source files in the project build phases and/or libraries in the Link Binary with Libraries section. With a few re-arrangements this problem should go away.